# What difference does it make if I inherit enum from Byte in C#

Tags: c#, enums

I am trying to figure out the difference between these two enums

```
    public enum EnumA
    {
        A = 1,
        B = 2,
        C = 3
    }
```

vs

```
   public enum EnumB : byte
    {
        A = 1,
        B = 2,
        C = 3
    }
```

I know that the default base type of enum is int, so If I change base type to byte how its going to impact?

Comment: If you store the enum value anywhere (like a database, binary file, network packet), it will take 1 byte instead of 4. You can also only have 256 values for the byte enum (or 8 unique flags), whereas the int one can have many, many more (2,147,483,647, 32 unique flags). The int enum can have negative values, the byte one only positive. Its also important in interop that you have type widths that match COM so you don't get strange COM errors.

Comment: Correction, an int (signed) can have 4,294,967,295 values if you include all the negative numbers, the same number of values as a uint (obviously, they are the same width).

Comment: @RonBeyer thanks for your explanation, one more thing, would there be any change in behavior other then the one that you mentioned above, I mean way of dealing with the values etc?

Comment: No, it shouldn't affect any other kinds of operations, any kind of enumeration operation that is valid on a int backed enum is valid on any other backed enum. I'm not sure what operations you'd be concerned about? Usually enum operations boil down to bitwise operators (&, |, !, etc), conditionals (if, switch)... Only thing I can think about is typecasting to the wrong underlying type (uint backed to int) and getting overflows.

Answer (score 9):

You will only be able to use value 0-255 for the enum. This is probably plenty, if you're not using the enum as flags, then you are limited to only 8 different flags.